# how to fix java.net.sll.SSlException: Tag mismatch warning

Tags: android, sdk, mobile-development, mismatch, sslexception

had this error while installing android studio,
please how to i resolve it

java.net.sll.SSlException: Tag mismatch warning: An error occured while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Tag mismatch!.

i tried turning off my antivirus and reinstalling but it didn't work, same error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.